# Get last 11 characters from URL

Tags: php, regex

I got this code:

```
if(preg_match("/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtu(.be\/|be\.com\/watch\?v=)(\w{11})$/", $url)){
        preg_match("/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtu(.be\/|be\.com\/watch\?v=)(\w{11})$/", $url, $matches);
        $vid = str_replace(' ', '', $matches[0]);
}
```

That pretty much checks if the URL is a Youtube video. How do I assign the last 11 characters from the URL to the `$vid` variable?

Example:

URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASDASDASDAS

```
$vid = ASDASDASDAS
```

Comment: Maybe `explode('v=',$url)[1]`?

Comment: Or maybe the function parse_url();

Comment: `$vid = ASDASDASDAS` you mean `$vid = "ASDASDASDAS";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't want to check for the last 11 characters, because the video ID might be changed any time to a different length. What you should always do is make something flexible enough. So in this case, you should check for `?.*v=([^&]+)`, since that will get the match until the next `&`. So your code would look like this:

```
//make this a variable, since you're using it multiple times.
$re = "/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtu(.be|be\.com)\/watch\?.*?v=([^&#]+).*$/";
if (preg_match($re, $url)){
        preg_match($re, $url, $matches);
        $vid = $matches[2]; //the 2nd group in the match, so the 2nd set of ()s
}
```

In that code, video urls that contain other URL parameters will also still work, and it's much more flexible with the length of the video ID.

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/bZ6nR8/1) - look to the right where it says `2.`, it will mention the video ID there (which is what's put inside `$vid`).

Comment: [a-zA-Z0-9_\-] or at least [^&#] is much more safer. Moreover you running are regex two times... it could be check for existence of match after first run

Comment: This worked thanks! The only issue with it is that the some URLs will have additional info in them such as "&list=..." right after the 11 characters, how do I ignore everything that comes after the 11 characters?

Comment: @Muki That's exactly what this code does: it only matches the part of `v=` until the next `&` or `#`, or until the end of the URL. That's what the `[^&#]+` part does: it matches anything *other than* the `&` or `#` characters. That way group 2 (accessed via `$matches[2]`) will only contain the actual video ID. I've added a link to a [demonstration](http://regex101.com/r/bZ6nR8/1) of the regex to my answer too. PS: if this answer fixed your problem, could you please mark it as accepted via the checkmark to the left of this answer? Thanks, and I hope it helped!

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed that, it's working great! Thanks for posting the demo too, great website that I didn't know about. May I ask if there are any regex tutorials that you would suggest? I started with this today so I'm still lost :/

Comment: @Muki well, I personnally learnt regex by trying it a lot, and using http://regexr.com as a reference for what does what in regex. I'd recommend http://regex101.com more now though, because it has a more user-friendly interface in my opinion (I just mentioned regexr because that's what I used before I knew regex101). You can just use the cheatsheet there to find what each part of regex does. And if you're stuck, of course you can try googling it, or asking it here if that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
$vid = substr($url,strlen($url)-11);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) functions will do the job ( no need for regular expressions ):

```
$link = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASDASDASDAS';
parse_str( parse_url( $link, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $query );

print_r( $query );
/*
Array
(
    [v] => ASDASDASDAS
)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward (correct) answers have been made, but I would encourage you to take a look at [oembed standard](http://oembed.com/) and library for php like https://code.google.com/p/php-oembed/. This would help you get info from almost all image/video services out there, generate embed code and more.